# How to start a background process in QNX using mkifs script?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, qnx-ifs

I have a `mkifs` script file with `.build` extension for building a qnx `.ifs` image. I would like to start a process in background when my QNX is booted with the image. The process is a service which waits for incoming requests and never ends.

I'm wondering how could I define my process in the `.build` file to run it in background.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be your answer:

"If you specify an ampersand (&) after the command line, the program runs in the background, and Neutrino doesn't wait for the program to finish before continuing with the next line in the script. If you don't specify the ampersand, and the program doesn't exit, then the rest of the script is never executed. The system isn't fully operational until the boot script finishes."[1]

so put this in your buildfile:

```
[+script] .script = {

    "do-stuff" &

}
```

your Buildfile should already have the "script" part

[1] http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/building/building_nto.html